# To find common difference of a logarithmic AP.

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

> **Ques:** If $a,b,c$ are in GP and $\log_ba,\log_cb,\log_ac$ are in AP. Then find the common difference of AP.

**Here's what I did:** $\Rightarrow b^2=ac$
$\Rightarrow 2\log b=\log a+\log c$ i.e. $\log a,\log b,\log c$ are in AP.

Now using the AP we get, $2\log_cb=\log_ba+\log_ac$ and we have to find
$\log_ac-\log_cb$ or $\log_cb-\log_ba$.

I have problem coping with the bases. Help me I know the answer(it is $3/2$). Maybe I'm a bit weak with logarithms, thats why I can't solve this.
 Please Help me. Thank you.

Comment: What are $GP$ and $AP$?

Comment: Arithmetic,Geometric progressions. My mistake, in my country teachers use these terms always,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

WLOG $b=ar,c=ar^2$

$$P=\log_ba=\dfrac{\log a}{\log a+\log r}$$

$$Q=\log_cb=\dfrac{\log a+\log r}{\log a+2\log r}$$

$$R=\log_ac=\dfrac{\log a+2\log r}{\log a}$$

Use  $P+R=2Q$ to find the relation between $\log a,\log r$

Comment: Thanks but it is rather a trivial solution. I will try it though.

Comment: I got the answer. But it is a bit long solution for an MCQ question. :D

Comment: @LoveInvariants, If you got the answer, why don't you post it in your original post, so that other readers will also understand. I wasted  so many papers, but i couldn't find a,b,c(in G.P.) and common difference between $log_c b-log_b a$

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod- You would get a cubic relation between $\log_a$ and $\log_r$ which would easily reduce to quadratic. I found it easy but cumbersome. I'm searching for an easier method though. I would post it when I get time today.

Comment: @LoveInvariants, a=1,b=1,c=1. Common difference  of  $\frac32$  between $\log_ba$ and $\log_cb$ is wrong.

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod- My mistake I didn't mention $a\ne b\ne c$

Comment: @LoveInvariants, If $a\not=b\not=c$, then i think  it is impossible to answer this question.

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod- No not impossible. If you take $\log a,\log b$ as some variable and use $P+R=2Q$ as said above. You would get ratio of $\log a,\log b$.